# Open new window and run javascript on that new widnow

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I go about opening a new Google Chrome window with javascript (opener via npm), and then fill out a form on that newly opened window?

Currently, I have:

```
// 2 arrays for storing account creation info
var opener = require('opener')
var newWindow = opener('URL HERE')
```

how would I go about attaching to that new window and running code on it to fill out a form? I'm running the javascript code via node in the Mac terminal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at selenium and nightwatch -  http://nightwatchjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will have to design your form, and host it where opener can actually access it. I've not used opener before, but from what I can see it's job is to open the url you pass as parameter, in a new browser process. Nothing more.

Designing and handling the submission of the form is up to you. No magic. No shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium for browser automation. Here is a link to the docs of selenium.
http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html

Here is a code to solve your problem with selenium

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('url to form');
var form = driver.findElement(By.css('form'));
var element = form.findElement(By.css('input[type=file]'));
element.sendKeys('/path/to/file.txt');
form.submit();
driver.quit();
```